# How do you add a unique field (non empty) field to an existing model in Django?

Tags: django

I have a model that looks like so:

```
class FoodPreferences(models.Model):
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(to='Food', db_index=True,
                                      through='FoodToPreferenceMap')
    is_vegan = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    some_new_unique_field = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

and now I want to add the `some_new_unique_field` to the model, but because it has no default value migrations would ask me for a new value. The field is supposed to be computed based on each row's foods values. How should I do approach this? is it possible to set a default value to be computed dynamically?

EDIT:

I'm giving custom migrations a try and here's my migration:

```
def gen_stuff(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'foodpreferences')
    while MyModel.objects.filter(some_new_unique_field__isnull=True).exists():
        with transaction.atomic():
            for row in MyModel.objects.filter(some_new_unique_field__isnull=True)[:1000]:
                row.some_new_unique_field = row.generate_new_field_stuff()
                row.save(update_fields=['some_new_unique_field'])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('stars_api', '0074_foodpreferences_ some_new_unique_field'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(gen_stuff, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop)
    ]
```

but I'm running into

```
AttributeError: 'FoodPreferences' object has no attribute 'generate_new_field_stuff'
```

EDIT: Fixed it, it was creating a shallow copy using get_model

Comment: You can edit the migration file to compute the value on a per row basis

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields.

Comment: @knbk I wrote my custom migration but I'm running into an object has no attribute error when running the migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion given on the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields). You can give it a try. And in short it says:

- First  creat a migration that allows the `new_field` to be nullable;
- Then create another migration that populates the `new_field` with proper values to every row in the model;
- Then another migration which adds the not-null constraint in the column.

Comment: Hey I took this approach but I'm running into this issue `object has no attribute` I'll edit my question